# Unpickle dictionary containing pytorch model not on cpu

Tags: python, pytorch, pickle

I was training a machine learning model using pytorch. I saved the data in a dictionary that I pickled, but I also did the mistake of saving the model in the same dictionary without sending it to the cpu (at least I think this is the mistake). When I try to unpickle the dictionary containing the model I get the following error message:

> RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.

Is there any way to unpickle the data somehow?

Comment: You have multiple modules that can help. [realpython python pickle module and others](https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the torch.load() function with the map_location parameter set to `torch.device('cpu')`. something like this:

```
import torch

saved_data = torch.load('saved_data.pkl', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model = saved_data['model']
```